# How will i identify which evaluation metric should i use for classification problem statement in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-science, confusion-matrix, supervised-learning

Which Evaluation metric should i use for classification problem statement ? On what factor should i decide ?
1. **Accuracy**
2. **F1 Score**
3. **AUC ROC Score**
4. **Log Loss**

Answer (score 0):

**Accuracy** is a great metric when you are working with a balanced dataset. It's the number of true predictions over the total number of predictions.

**F1 Score** is a great metric when you want to maximaze the precision and the recall of the prediction, it's also great to unbalanced datasets.

**AUC ROC Score** represents how much of your data is covered by the algorithm. I really like using this evaluation metric, it works well for both balanced and unbalanced datasets.

**Log Loss** is the logarithmic loss of the prediction, beased on the cross-entropy between the predicted label and the true label. I never used this metric before.